# htaccess redirect https www AND http www to https non-www subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess

I'm having trouble redirecting with my htaccess file.

What I'm trying to redirect:

```
https://www.example.com
https://example.com
http://www.example.com
http://example.com
```

to

```
https://example.com/subdirectory and keep the url https://example.com
```

This is what I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ example.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www. example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !folder/
RewriteRule (.*) /subdirectory/$1 [L]
```

but it doesn't redirect https://www.example.com to https://example.com

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ example.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www. example.com$
```

and replace with

```
#Redirect www and http
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```